# jquery fetch answer on click submit(sources data from database)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

hello i have a piece of code  here, it fetches data(questions and options) from the database. all i need help with is that i want to get all the answer on click submit button

```
    <?php
$res = $conn->query("select * from questions where category_id='$category' ORDER BY RAND()") ;
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($res);
$i=1;
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){?>

    <?php if($i==1){?>        
    <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
        <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p>
        <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>                     
        <br/>
        <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button'>Next</button>
    </div>    

    <?php }elseif($i<1 || $i<$rows){?>
    <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
        <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p>
        <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>                     
        <br/>
        <button id='pre<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button>       
        <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button' >Next</button>
    </div>

    <?php }elseif($i==$rows){?>
    <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
        <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p>
        <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>                     
        <br/>
        <button id='pre<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button>       
        <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success submit' type='submit'>Finish</button>
        </div>
    <?php 

    } 
$i++;
} ?>

</form>
```

please guide me with a jquery code that can fetch all answer onsubmit.
This is what i have tried below

```
  $(document).on('click','.submit',function(){
 var answer = [];
$. each($(this.checked), function(){
 answers. push($(this). val());
 });
 alert("your answers are: " + answers. join(", "));
```

Comment: `$('form').on('submit', function(){ alert(...) })`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
    var answer = [];
    $(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){
        answers.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert("your answers are: " + answers.join(", "));

    //return false to prevent submission
});
```

This part

```
  $(this.checked)
```

Made no sense, `this` in this context is the `.submit` button.  So that doesn't tell us how to find the checkboxes/radio buttons.

In any case in jQuery we can use `:checked` for checkboxes/radio buttons so you can do above or `if($(foo).is(':checked'))` for example.

Instead we should use the form's submit action as our event, because then `this` is the form which contains the checkboxes/radio buttons.  So that makes it much easier to find them.  You can use the buttons click event, but then you need to do something like this:

```
 //instead of $(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').each( ... )
 $('.submit').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('form').find('input[type="radio"]:checked').each( ... );

        //...
 });
```

Because `$(this)` will be the button, so we have to get the parent form, then get the checkboxes/radio buttons.

Comment: i have all these  in my vs code i cant put it on stackoverflow.The real help i need is that i want to get the answers on submit with jquery

Comment: brilliant!!! i need to get answers of each `:checked`  see what i did        `      `$('.submit').click(function(){  
var answer = [];
$(this).closest('form').find('input[type="radio"]:checked').each( 
  answer. push($(this). val());
 );`